# Error during creation of SXA Tenant in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sxa

Powershell scrips for the creation of Tenant accidentally stopped to work

1. I click the right mouse button on the content item and select "Insert>Tenant"
2. I fill the name of a tenant and unselect all modules
3. I click OK button

Execution fails near to the end with the message:
[image]

SPE log contains next error:

```
2488 11:50:30 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
2488 11:50:30 INFO  Script item set to master:\system\Modules\PowerShell\Script Library\SXA\SXA - Scaffolding\Content Editor\Insert Item\Tenant in ScriptSession $scriptSession$|tbw531otm3f1x2g5j541xbhp|a8877403-33fc-44b7-8034-a98672829163.
ManagedPoolThread #7 11:50:30 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|tbw531otm3f1x2g5j541xbhp|a8877403-33fc-44b7-8034-a98672829163'.
2372 11:50:47 INFO  Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider5.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
2372 11:50:47 INFO  Executing a script in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|tbw531otm3f1x2g5j541xbhp|c4d6c3db-40bf-49b2-9c36-9b40fc9de366'.
ManagedPoolThread #7 11:51:02 ERROR The property 'Modules' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

What could be the reason for this error?
How to troubleshoot this problem?

Update:
I have enabled [verbose logging](https://alan-null.github.io/2019/12/sxa-scaffolding-debugging).
I get next info in the logs:

```
...
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-ProjectTemplateBasedOnBaseTemplate - Begin
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-ProjectTemplateBasedOnBaseTemplate - Process
VERBOSE: Found home item (/sitecore/templates/Project/a3/Home). Changing base template
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-ProjectTemplateBasedOnBaseTemplate - Begin
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-ProjectTemplateBasedOnBaseTemplate - Process
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-ProjectTemplateBasedOnBaseTemplate - End
VERBOSE: Found tenant page item (/sitecore/templates/Project/a3/Page)
VERBOSE: oldValue: {E9272B0E-3BBA-445F-8634-224D68966BB9}
VERBOSE: newValue: {F7F5538B-C54A-4F88-ACA8-DCBE143087E7}|{E9272B0E-3BBA-445F-8634-224D68966BB9}
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Get-ProjectTemplateBasedOnBaseTemplate - End
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Invoke-ModuleScriptBody - End
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Invoke-ExecuteScript - End
VERBOSE: Cmdlet Invoke-TenantAction - End
Add-Tenant : The property 'Modules' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:133 char:17
+ ...             Add-Tenant $Model.TenantLocation ($Model.TenantName) ($Mo ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-Tenant], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException,Add-Tenant
```

Comment: You can try downloading the SXA package and install. Then check.

Comment: You can reinstall SXA (it looks to me that one field is missing) or you can try debugging using this
https://alan-null.github.io/2019/12/sxa-scaffolding-debugging

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak See additional logs after enabling verbose logging

Comment: @Anton please validate if your Tenant template (from tenant templates) has this base template {3BC304DB-FE8F-4AA8-B95C-8C331E823F4C} (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/_Modules`)
or if you have it at all in your db.
You just pasted some part of logs the next thing to check is to validate if this action was executed

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/Scaffolding Tenant Setup/Tenant Modules`

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak

Yes, _Modules is present in the database. And Tenant template is inherited from _Modules template

Comment: @SumitBhatia Reinstallation of SXA didn't fix the problem.